# How to erase memory while using watchdog in python

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory, watchdog

I used watchdog to monitor file creating in a folder.
Whenever a parquet file is created, watchdog will call python script to read the parquet file.

When the watchdog program is first run, the memory usage is 90KB.
After finished reading first parquet file, the memory usage is 100KB. I delete all the dataframe when the python script finished executing.

When 2nd parquet file is created, watchdog run the python script by staring memory usage of 100KB and after finished reading 2nd parquet file, the memory usage is 101KB.

Why the watchdog does not release memory when the first file finished executing?

**How to write the script if I want the watchdog script to reset the memory after finished executing every file?** i.e., When 1st parquet file is created, watchdog call python script by starting memory 90KB and ending with 100KB. When 2nd parquet file is created, watchdog call python script by starting memory 90KB and ending with 100KB instead of starting memory 100KB and ending with 101KB.

The following is the watchdog script and reading parquet file python script:

*Reading parquet file python script*

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import gc, psutil

def usage():
  process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
  return process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)

def readfile(filename):
   gc.enable()
   gc.get_threshold()
   gc.get_count()
   print("Before reading parquet: "+str(usage()))
   df = pd.read_parquet(filename)
   print("After reading parquet: "+str(usage()))
   del df
   gc.collect()
   print("After deleting df: "+str(usage()))
```

*Watchdog script*

```
import os, sys, time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from utility.python_script import readfile as rf
class MonitorFolder(FileSystemEventHandler):
  def on_created(self,event):
     filename = event.src_path
     rf(filename)
if __name__=="__main__":
  path_ = "C:\\folder1\\folder2"
  event_handler_=MonitorFolder()
  observer = PollingObserver(timeout=0.1)
  observer.schedule(event_handler,path=path_, recursive = True)
  observer.start()
  try:
    while (True):
        time.sleep(0.1)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Releasing memory in your script (via Python's memory management system) doesn't mean the Python *runtime* is releasing the memory back to the OS immediately (or ever). Really, this isn't something to worry about unless your OS runs out of memory before your script exits.

Comment: My script will run 24/7 and if the python does not release memory back to OS even though I delete the dataframe object, so there will be out of memory at some time. 
May I know how to write python code to release memory back to OS?

Comment: You need to test your code more extensively than you currently have. You are using trivial amounts of memory so far; run it longer and on bigger files to see if memory growth remains a problem.